# How to solve a combinatorial logic with an output feeding back to the input, forming a loop?

Tags: loops, vhdl, fsm

I have this warnig in my code for a FSM:

```
WARNING:Xst:2170 - Unit P22_MustangSecuentialTailLight_Structural : the following signal(s) form a combinatorial loop: Lights<5>, U1/next_state_cmp_eq0000, next_state_int<0>, pres_state_int<0>.

WARNING:Xst:2170 - Unit P22_MustangSecuentialTailLight_Structural : the following signal(s) form a combinatorial loop: Lights<4>, next_state_int<1>, pres_state_int<1>.

WARNING:Xst:2170 - Unit P22_MustangSecuentialTailLight_Structural : the following signal(s) form a combinatorial loop: next_state_int<2>, U1/next_state_cmp_eq0003, Lights<3>, pres_state_int<2>.

WARNING:Xst:2170 - Unit P22_MustangSecuentialTailLight_Structural : the following signal(s) form a combinatorial loop: next_state_int<3>, pres_state_int<4>, U1/next_state_cmp_eq0013, pres_state_int<3>, Lights<2>, next_state_int<4>.
```

Its for a loop made in the code, the image of my diagram[image]

But that enbedded signal(pres_state_int) is necessary for update the next state logic block. The code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use work.States.all;

entity P22_MustangSecuentialTailLight_Structural is
    Port  ( Lturn     : in   STD_LOGIC;
           Rturn     : in   STD_LOGIC;
           Hazard    : in   STD_LOGIC;
           Rst       : in   STD_LOGIC;
              Break     : in   STD_LOGIC;
           Clk100MHz : in   STD_LOGIC;
           Lights    : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0));
end P22_MustangSecuentialTailLight_Structural;

architecture Behavioral of P22_MustangSecuentialTailLight_Structural is

    component NextStateLogic
        port ( 
                BLRH       : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0); 
                pres_state : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
                next_state : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0));
        end component;

    component CurrentStateRegister
        port ( 
                pres_state_b : out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
                next_state_b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
                Rst          : in STD_LOGIC;
                Clk          : in STD_LOGIC );
        end component;

    component OutputLogic
        port ( 
                pres_state_c : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
                Lights     : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0));
        end component;  

    component Clk1Hz
        port (
              Rst       : in    STD_LOGIC;
           Clk_in    : in    STD_LOGIC;
           Clk_out   : out   STD_LOGIC);
    end component;

    --Embedded signal declaration
    signal LRH_int        : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    signal next_state_int : state_values := ST0;
    signal pres_state_int : state_values := ST0;
    signal Clk1Hz_int     : STD_LOGIC;

    begin 
    LRH_int <= Break & Lturn & Rturn & Hazard;


    U1 : NextStateLogic 
    port map(
        BLRH       => LRH_int,
        pres_state => pres_state_int,
        next_state => next_state_int
        );

    U2 : CurrentStateRegister 
    port map(
        pres_state_b => pres_state_int,
        next_state_b => next_state_int,
        Rst => Rst,
        Clk => Clk1Hz_int
        );

    U3 : OutputLogic 
    port map(
        pres_state_c => pres_state_int,
        Lights     => Lights
        );

    U4 : Clk1Hz
    port map(
              Rst      => Rst,
           Clk_in   => Clk100MHz,
           Clk_out  => Clk1Hz_int
        );      

end Behavioral;
```

Next is the package use for encoding the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

package States is

      subtype state_values is std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
  constant ST0: state_values := "00000";
  constant ST1: state_values := "00001"; 
  constant ST2: state_values := "00010";
  constant ST3: state_values := "00011";
  constant ST4: state_values := "00100";
  constant ST5: state_values := "00101";
  constant ST6: state_values := "00110";
  constant ST7: state_values := "00111";
  constant ST8: state_values := "01000";
  constant ST9: state_values := "01001";
  constant ST10: state_values := "01010";
  constant ST11: state_values := "01011";
  constant ST12: state_values := "01100";
  constant ST13: state_values := "01101";
  constant ST14: state_values := "01110";
  constant ST15: state_values := "01111";
  constant ST16: state_values := "10000";
  signal pres_state, next_state: state_values;


end States;
```

NextStateLogic component code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use work.States.all;


entity NextStateLogic is
            Port(   BLRH       : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0); 
                pres_state : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
                next_state : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0));
end NextStateLogic;

architecture NextStateLogicl of NextStateLogic is

begin 

FSM: process (pres_state, BLRH)
  begin
    case pres_state is

      when "00000" => 
        case BLRH is
          when "0000"  => next_state <= "00000";--ST0; -- All off
          when "0010"  => next_state <= "00100";--ST4; -- Right Turn
          when "0100"  => next_state <= "00111";--ST7; -- Left Turn
             when "0110"  => next_state <= "00101";--ST5; -- All off
          when others  => next_state <= "00001";--ST1; -- Hazard
        end case;
      when "00001"         => next_state <= "00010";--ST2;
        when "00010"         => next_state <= "00011";
        when "00011"         => 
            case BLRH is
          when "1000"  => next_state <= "00011"; -- Break
          when "1110"  => next_state <= "00011"; -- 
          when "1010"  => next_state <= "01101"; -- Right Turn & Break
             when "1100"  => next_state <= "01010"; -- Left Turn & Break
          when others  => next_state <= "00000"; -- Hazard
        end case;
      when "00100"         => next_state <= "00101";
      when "00101"         => next_state <= "00110";
      when "00110"         => next_state <= "00000";
      when "00111"         => next_state <= "01000";
      when "01000"         => next_state <= "01001";    
      when "01001"         => next_state <= "01010";
        when "01010"        => next_state <= "01011";
        when "01011"        => next_state <= "01100";
        when "01100"        => 
            case BLRH is
          when "1100"  => next_state <= "01111"; -- Right Turn & Break
          when "1010"  => next_state <= "10000"; -- Left Turn & Break
          when others  => next_state <= "00000"; 
        end case;
        when "01101"        => next_state <= "01110";
        when "01110"        => next_state <= "01100";
        when "01111"        => next_state <= "01010";
        when "10000"        => next_state <= "01101";

 -- Include when others to avoid latches  
      when others      => next_state <= "00000";
    end case;
  end process FSM;




end NextStateLogicl;
```

CurrentStateRegister component code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity CurrentStateRegister is
            Port( 
                pres_state_b : out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
                next_state_b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
                Rst          : in STD_LOGIC;
                Clk          : in STD_LOGIC
                );
end CurrentStateRegister;

architecture CurrentStateRegister of CurrentStateRegister is

begin

StateReg: process (Clk,Rst,next_state_b)
  begin
    if (Rst = '1') then 
      pres_state_b <= "00000";
    elsif Clk = '1' then
      pres_state_b <= next_state_b;
        else
        pres_state_b<= "00000";
    end if;
  end process StateReg;




end CurrentStateRegister;
```

OutputLogic component code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity OutputLogic is
Port( 
                pres_state_c : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
                Lights     : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0));

end OutputLogic;

architecture OutputLogic of OutputLogic is

begin 

Outputs: process (pres_state_c)
  begin
    case pres_state_c is

      when "00000" => Lights <= "000000";
        ----------------------------------------------- Hazard
        when "00001" => Lights <= "001100";
      when "00010" => Lights <= "011110";
      when "00011" => Lights <= "111111";
      -----------------------------------------------   Right Turn  
      when "00100" => Lights <= "000100";
      when "00101" => Lights <= "000110";
      when "00110" => Lights <= "000111";
        ----------------------------------------------- Left Turn
      when "00111" => Lights <= "001000";
      when "01000" => Lights <= "011000";
      when "01001" => Lights <= "111000";
        ----------------------------------------------- Right Turn & Break
        when "01010" => Lights <= "001111";
      when "01011" => Lights <= "011111";
        -----------------------------------------------
      when "01111" => Lights <= "000111";
        when "01100" => Lights <= "111111"; -- Common Case
        when "10000" => Lights <= "111000";
        ----------------------------------------------- Left Turn & Break
      when "01101" => Lights <= "111100";
      when "01110" => Lights <= "111110";

      when others => Lights <= "000000";
   end case;
  end process Outputs;



end OutputLogic;
```

And finally the Clk1Hz component code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Clk1Hz is

        port (
              Rst       : in    STD_LOGIC;
           Clk_in    : in    STD_LOGIC;
           Clk_out   : out   STD_LOGIC);
end Clk1Hz;

architecture Clk1Hz of Clk1Hz is
-- Definition of embedded signals and constants
  -- Constants used for frequency division
  constant Fosc    : integer := 100000000;   --Frecuencia del oscilador de tabletas NEXYS 3
  constant Fdiv    : integer := 5;           --Frecuencia deseada del divisor
  constant CtaMax  : integer := Fosc / Fdiv; --Cuenta maxima a la que hay que llegar
  -- Signal used by the frequency division process
  signal Cont      : integer range 0 to CtaMax;

begin
  -- Frequency divider to obtain a 2Hz signal from
  -- the 100 MHz board oscillator
  FreqDiv: process (Rst, Clk_in)
  begin
    if Rst = '1' then
       Cont <= 0;
     elsif (rising_edge(Clk_in)) then
       if Cont = CtaMax - 1 then
        Cont      <= 0;
        Clk_out    <= '1';
      else        
         Cont      <= Cont + 1;
          Clk_out    <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
  end process FreqDiv;




end Clk1Hz;
```

Iam missing something?? Is there another way to instanciate the component NextStateLogic?

Thanks:D

Comment: Without the rest of the code we can only guess. My guess would be there is something wrong in the entity you have used for component "CurrentStateRegister". Best thing you can do: Get it working in simulation (Xilinx ISIM is OK) before you try synthesis again.

Comment: My guess was right : see Godel's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CurrentStateRegister, you need to test for `rising_edge(clk)` instead of `clk = '1'`. Your current code infers a latch instead of a register, causing a loop whenever `clk = '1'`. Also, lose the final `else` in the ControlStateRegister module:

```
StateReg: process (Clk,Rst,next_state_b)
  begin
    if (Rst = '1') then 
      pres_state_b <= "00000";
    elsif (rising_edge(Clk)) then
      pres_state_b <= next_state_b;
    end if;
  end process StateReg;
```